# Did Oscar's date deceive Emily in an episode of The Odd Couple?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-odd-couple

About halfway through episode 4 in season 1 of *The Odd Couple* from 2015 ('The Blind Leading the Blind Date'), Oscar's date deceives Emily out of 20 dollars with a puzzle (?):

> **Oscar's date:** Excuse me, can I get back ten for ten ones?
>   **Emily:** Oh sure... Here, you gave me a ten with the ones.
>   **Oscar's date:** Whoops. Keep it. I'll give you another single and then you can give me a twenty.
>   **Emily:** Yeah, that works.

And she gives Oscar's date 20 bucks.

What just happened? How did Oscar's date deceive Emily?

Comment: Did she give Emily the ones *after* Emily gave her the ten dollar bill? ;)

Comment: Yes. She gave Emily 1x9 + 1x10 dollars AFTER receiving 10 dollars from Emily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known scam among grifters, and it's not its first appearance in the media. [Wiki elaborates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_confidence_tricks):

> **Change raising**, also known as a **quick-change artist**, is a common short con and involves an offer to change an amount of money with someone, while at the same time taking change or bills back and forth to confuse the person as to how much money is actually being changed. **The most common form, "the Short Count", has been featured prominently in several movies about grifting, notably *The Grifters*, *Criminal*, *Nine Queens*, and *Paper Moon*.**
>
> For example, a con artist shopping at a gas station pays for a cheap item (under a dollar) and gives the clerk a ten dollar bill. The con gets back nine ones and the change and then tells the clerk he has a one and will exchange ten ones for a ten. **This is what the scam artist is doing: getting the clerk to hand over the $10 *before* handing over the $1 bills. Then the scam artist hands over nine ones and the $10. The clerk will assume there has been a mistake and offer to swap the ten for a one. Then the con will probably just say: "Here's another one, give me a $20 and we're even." Notice that the scam artist just swapped $10 for $20. *The $10 was the store's money, not the con's.***

Here's a video that explains how the con works: